# Excel 2013 time & days schedule overlaps

Tags: excel-formula

Without using VB, in Excel 2013 how can I look for schedule overlaps for instructors --they can't teach 2 classes at same time on same day.
Example: ** These 2 are a problem and need to stand out as an error.

```
Course Title    Time    Days
Human Implications I    1:30pm-3:30pm   M/W
Principles of Biology   3:30pm-5:30pm   W
**Principles of Biology 9:30am-10:45am  M/W**
**Principles of Human I 9:30am-10:45am  M/W**
Genetics    9:10am-10:45am  T/R/F
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into SUMPRODUCT. Select your whole table and then add a new conditional formatting rule. Choose "Use a formula" and try this. Then change the "Format" to color the cells when they match. I did have to change your format as I could not figure a way for excel to determine the times and days when they are all in one cell. This is the format I used. I started the table on cell C2.

```
Class Title        Start Time    End Time    Day1   Day2   Day3
Principles of Bio   9:30 am       10:45 am    M      W   



=SUMPRODUCT(($D$3:$D$7<=$E3)*($E$3:$E$7>=$D3)*($F$3:$F$7=$F3)*($G$3:$G$7=$G3)*($H$3:$H$7=$H3))>1=TRUE
```

This works by checking if the start time is before the other classes end times, the end time is after the start time, and the days are the same. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try!

Comment: I did not get it to work... did you actually have data from C2:H7 and get it to work?  I entered all my data, created the conditional formatting rule using the "use a formaula"

Comment: I did get it to work. The headers were in the 2nd row and started in column C. So the first class title would be in C3, second class in C4 and so on through column H. Make sure the time cells are formatted properly because it won't work if excel interprets "9:30 am" as a string and not a time.